# Calling function: select_by_value Selenium Python

Tags: python, function, selenium, select, drop-down-menu

I'm still beginner... so I have the following classes and functions in different files:

```
def select_element_by_value(self, value, *selector):
    select = Select(self.find_element(*selector))
    select.select_by_value(value)
```

then I have this in another file:

```
class SiteList(HomePage):

SITE_LIST_SELECTOR = (By.ID, "site_label")

    def select_site(self):
        self.select_element_by_value("10", *self.SITE_LIST_SELECTOR)
```

and finally my script file contains:

```
site_table = SiteList(driver=self.driver)
site_table.select_site()
```

It works however I want to be able to select just the value ("10") directly from the script file itself not like it is now inside a function in the other file. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this?

```
class SiteList(HomePage):

SITE_LIST_SELECTOR = (By.ID, "site_label")

    def select_site(self, value):
        self.select_element_by_value(value, *self.SITE_LIST_SELECTOR)
```

and

```
site_table = SiteList(driver=self.driver)
site_table.select_site("10")
```